# Why do I end up with 8 extra spaces when applying the transform from within MatLab rather than letting Firefox handle it?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

I have the following structure:

```
<suite>
  <faults>
    <fault componentName="comp1">
      <introduceWhen>Time1</introduceWhen>
      <signals>
        <signal name="sig11" value="1"/>
        <signal name="sig22" value="1"/>
      </signals>
    </fault>
    <fault componentName="comp2">
      <introduceWhen>Time2</introduceWhen>
      <signals>
        <signal name="sig44" value="0"/>
      </signals>
    </fault>
  </faults>
</suite>
```

And using the follwing template I extract some data and put it in a table cell that has `white-space: pre` set, in order to allow me to put each fault on a new line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>
<xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"/>

<xsl:template match="/suite">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Space Demo</title>
      <style>
        td.faults {text-align: left; white-space: pre;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="faults">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="faults"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="faults">
  <xsl:for-each select="fault">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@componentName, ' ', introduceWhen, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="signals/signal">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@value, ' ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works exactly as I want it to if I only display the XML in Firefox, with the XSLT as a stylesheet. But if I apply the transform in MatLab, the resulting HTML gets generated with an extra 8 spaces after the `$1&#xA;`. MatLab uses Saxon 6.5.5 for XSLT processing.

I tried using the following template to trim the string, but it made no difference:

```
<xsl:template name="trim">
  <xsl:param name="str"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($str) &gt; 0 and substring($str, 1, 1) = ' '">
      <xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="str">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($str, 2)"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($str) &gt; 0 and substring($str, string-length($str)) = ' '">
      <xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="str">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($str, 1, string-length($str)-1)"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

What can I do to get rid of the extra 8 spaces? There is a working example of this behavior here: http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuP4

Comment: Your XSLT above has this odd character `¨` on the penultimate line. This would explain some unexpected output.

Comment: Please post a complete, **reproducible** example. The template you have posted has invalid syntax (e.g. `<xsl:value-of select=concat(@value, ' ')"/>` ) and we don't see the stylesheet headers - esp. the `xsl:output` settings.

Comment: Sorry, now there is a more complete, and correct, example. I'm working on an air-gapped network, so putting up examples here is a pain and errors easily creep in.

Comment: By "*extra 8 spaces after the `$1&#xA;`*" do you mean the **indent** of the `comp2 Time2 0 ` part?

Comment: Yes, there is also a newline and 8 spaces _after_ the `comp2 Time2 0` part, but they're hard to see in that when it's only one single table cell.

Comment: @Fylke Change the output method to `xml` and see what happens.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry for the delay. I changed it to XML and that indeed fixes the space issue! (at first I thought it broke my title tags, but it turns out I just viewed it in an ancient browser). So maybe put this in an answer? Why does this work though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indent is apparently an attempt of the Saxon processor to make the HTML code more pretty. Neither Xalan nor libxslt produce a similar indent.

Since HTML browsers ignore superfluous white space characters, the addition is harmless and I see no reason why you should be concerned.

Changing the output method to `xml` will remove the indent, because unlike with HTML, white space *can* be critical.

Comment: Do you think I should try and register this as a bug towards Saxon?

Comment: @Fylke I would try adding the `saxon` tag to your question first - that might produce a more authoritative response than I can provide.